# Proving the identity $\sum_{k=0}^{m} \binom{n-k}{m-k}= \binom{n+1}{m}$ .

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification, summation, binomial-coefficients, generating-functions

Today we started talking about generating functions in class. I came across this identity:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{m} \binom{n-k}{m-k}= \binom{n+1}{m}$$

Here is my proof for this identity (If it is wrong please tell me):

$$ \binom{n+1}{m} = \binom{n}{m}+\binom{n}{m-1} = \binom{n}{m}+\binom{n-1}{m-1}+\binom{n-1}{m-2}=\dots = \binom{n}{m}+\binom{n-1}{m-1}+ \dots + \binom{n-(m-1))}{n-(m-1)}+\binom{n-(m-1)}{0} =  \sum_{k=0}^{m} \binom{n-k}{m-k}$$

I understood that it is possible to prove identities using generating functions, so I would appreciate if you could help me prove this equality using **generating functions (or in any way that is different from mine)**.

Comment: I would bet a medium amount of money that this question already has answers on this site. Search on this site or try https://approach0.xyz/search/

Comment: @AdamRubinson I searched on this site before asking, unfortunately I didn't find answers. Thanks for the second site.

Comment: The set of strings with $m$ zeroes and $(1 +n)-m$ ones can be split into those that start with $1$, those that start with $0$ followed by $1$ (ie. $01$) , those that start with $2$  zeroes followed by $1$  (ie. $001$), .... and those that start with $m$ zeroes followed by $1$. Clasifying the strings based on the the number of $0$'s preceding the first $1$ gives the desired formula.

Answer (score 1):

Since you were asking about generating functions, here's one using that:
\begin{align*}
  \frac{1}{(1-x)}\cdot \frac{1}{(1-x)^k} &= \sum_{n\ge 0} \left(\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{i+k-1}{k-1}\right) x^n \\
   \frac{1}{(1-x)^{k+1}} &=  \sum_{n\ge 0} \binom{n+k}{k} x^n \\
\implies \sum_{i=0}^n \binom{i+k-1}{k-1} &= \binom{n+k}{k}
\end{align*}
hence completing the proof.

Notice that we have used
\begin{align*}
  \frac{1}{(1-x)^k} &= \sum_{i\ge 0} \binom{i+k-1}{k-1}\, x^i
\end{align*}